# Troubles in VSCode terminal because of user folder name

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm new in this environment and currently learning the basics of Python through YouTube courses. While using VSCode, I always encounter the same problem when I try to use the terminal. The command (like a pip install for ex) won't run because my users folder name has a space in it.
It shows "C:\User<my first name> " is not valid.
Otherwise when I run code with CodeRunner everything works fine.
I'm sorry to not adjoint a screenshot to it it seems I'm not able to.
Is there anyway to fix this?

Comment: Can you write the command you're trying and the exact error message?

Comment: You're not allowed to attach a screenshot because you're a new user. But the general preference on SO is to copy/paste the text instead of adding an image, that way it is searchable

Answer (score 1):

You can run the command using quotes.

It'd go something like:

```
python "C:\Users\My User\file.py"
```

Using quotes should solve your issue. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

People will probably say:

- Don't put spaces in your paths to begin with.
- Try updating VSCode?

If you're running the commands in the terminal, put quotes around the path. E.g., `python "path/to/spaced file.py"`.

Otherwise, if this is a task that you're running, simply put `""` around `${file}` in `tasks.json`.

Though, I strongly recommend not using spaces, and replacing with something like `-` or `_`, or just a capitalisation rule like `camelCase` or `PascalCase`.

Comment: OP said their home directory has a space in it. Not something that can easily be undone

Comment: Yes, i´m aware I shouldn´t use spaces in folder or file names.. the problem is that it is my users folder name and changing it might create a lot of problems for other apps.

Answer (score 0):

If you have successfully set the environment variables and selected the correct interpreter. Then using the `pip` command directly in the terminal to install the package will not cause an error.

[image]

If you cannot avoid using folder names that contain spaces, you can install the package in a terminal using a command in a format similar to the one below.

*just an example*

```
& "c:/Users/Admin/Desktop/My Name/.venv/Scripts/python.exe" -m pip install numpy
```

[image]